# Merce csv files (from a folder) into one, adding columns with different names using Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I need to merge several CSV files that are located in a folder into a single one.

My original data is like this

**y_1980.csv:**

```
     country   y_1980
0        afg    196
1        ago    125
2        alb     23
3          .      .
.          .      .
```

**y_1981.csv:**

```
     country   y_1981
0        afg    192
1        ago    120
2        alb     0
3          .      .
.          .      .
```

**y_20xx.csv:**

```
     country   y_20xx
0        afg    176
1        ago    170
2        alb     76
3          .      .
.          .      .
```

what I expect to get is something similar like this:

```
     country   y_1980   y_1981   ...   y_20xx    
0        afg      196      192   ...      176
1        ago      125      120   ...      170
2        alb       23        0   ...       76
3          .        .        .   ...        .
.          .        .        .   ...        .
```

So far, my current code is as follow but the result I get are the data frames are merging after the previous one:

```
interesting_files = glob.glob("/Users/Desktop/Data/*.csv") 

header_saved = True

with open('/Users/Desktop/Data/table.csv','wb') as fout:
    for filename in interesting_files:

        with open(filename) as fin:
            header = next(fin)
            if not header_saved:
                fout.write(header)
                header_saved = True
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Its much easier if you use `pandas`. Because it gets rid of the `for-loop` and keeps the memory foot print low. Also, it is more comprehensive. Let me know if you want pandas solution.

Comment: yes, I would like a pandas solution please

Comment: Check the answer. It will work elegantly and its more comprehensive. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas makes this quite easy.  With a loop and merge you can simply do:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

files = ['file1', 'file2']
dfs = None
for filename in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+')
    if dfs is None:
        dfs = df
    else:
        dfs = dfs.merge(df, how='outer')
    print(df)
print(dfs)
dfs.to_csv('file3', sep=' ')
```

**Results:**

```
  country  y_1980
0     afg     196
1     ago     125
2     alb      23

  country  y_1981
0     afg     192
1     ago     120
2     alb       0

  country  y_1980  y_1981
0     afg     196     192
1     ago     125     120
2     alb      23       0
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the code appears to run like:

- Open file #1
- Write header if not saved
- Write lines of data
- Open file #2
- ...etc

which concatenates all the data into a single file. It sounds like you actually want to join by the column "country" instead

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
csvs = glob.glob("*.csv")
dfs = []

for csv in csvs:
  dfs.append(pd.read_csv(csv))

merged_df = dfs[0]

for df in dfs[1:]:
  merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df,df,on=['country'])


merged_df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this code, but I'm getting this error:

---> 13 merged_df =  for df in dfs[1:]:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Modified my code to fix some formatting, but can you check to make sure that dfs actually contains a list of the dataframes that were read in? The for loop with `dfs[1:]` loops through the all but the first dataframe since it was assigned when `merged_df` was declared

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier if you use pandas. The reason being it will get rid of the `for-loop` issue and keeps the `memory footprint` low.

```
import pandas as pd

# read the files first

y_1980 = pd.read_csv('y_1980.csv', sep='\t')
y_1981 = pd.read_csv('y_1981.csv', sep='\t')
```

you may change the `sep` option if the values are separated by space using ' ' or ',' for comma.

```
# set 'country' as the index to use this value to merge.
y_1980 = y_1980.set_index('country', append=True)
y_1981 = y_1981.set_index('country', append=True)

print(y_1980)
print(y_1981)

            y_1980
    country        
  0 afg         196
  1 ago         125
  2 alb          23


             y_1980
    country        
  0 afg         192
  1 ago         120
  2 alb           0

# set the frames to merge. You can add as many dataframe as you want.
frames =[y_1980, y_1981]

# now merge the dataframe
merged_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1).reset_index(level=['country'])
print(result)

      country  y_1980  y_1980
0     afg     196     192
1     ago     125     120
2     alb      23       0
```

**Additional note:** if you want to merge only the keys that are present in all the frames you can add the option: `how='inner' and drop=na`. If you want to merge all the possible data in all the frames use `how='outer'`.

See this link for more detail: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html